# Get Channel Field Names from Channel Field IDs?

Tags: ee2

Is there an API that can get Channel Field Names being passed Channel Field IDs? I'm not looking for a third party solution. I can code a solution myself if that's the case.

Answer (score 3):

no, is not such function in  Channel Fields API  (api_channel_fields->get_settings is not worked as expected). 
So you can do query for now

```
$field_name = ee()->db->select('field_name')->where('field_id', '19')->get('channel_fields', 1);
echo $field_name->row()->field_name;
```